# cx_freeze fails to import psycopg2 shared lib at runtime

Tags: python, postgresql, shared-libraries, psycopg2, cx-freeze

I have built an executable using cxfreeze (inside a python3.2 virtualenv) on my local machine. 
The executable runs correctly on the local machine.

I'm trying to run the executable on a separate target machine (of identical OS and architecture), but get the following error:

```
  ...
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/python3env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_psycopg2__psycopg.py", line 18, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named None
```

All the shared library dependencies are met on the target machine (according to `ldd`).

Based on the trace my guess is that psycopg2 is trying to load the shared library `_psycopg.cpython-32mu.so` (locally `python3.2/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-32mu.so`) but can't find it at runtime.

I tried placing the library in the same directory as the executable and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but neither solved  the (assumed) problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `strace` on each process, it appears that the pure python version is looking for the file `_psycopg.cpython-32mu.so`

```
open("/home/chris/.virtualenvs/python3env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-32mu.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
```

Whereas the binary built by cxfreeze is looking for the file `psycopg2._psycopg.so`

```
open("/path/to/psycopg2._psycopg.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

`md5sum` reveals these files to be identical, so it appears that the cxfreeze process changes the expected name of the dynamic library. It's worth noting that a version of this library correctly name for the target *is* included in the `dist` directory output by cxfreeze.